# Jquery computing between text and number fields

Tags: jquery

I have it all set up. I am trying to make a computation between the price(number input) and quantity(text input), but when I try to pass this value to the input (.total) it returns a NaN.

Example:

```
<input type="number" class="price" value="10"/>
<input type="text" class="quantity" value="10,15"/>
<input type="text" class="total" value="NaN"/>
```

Everything works in the console. Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 function compute() {
     var row = $(this).closest('tr');
     var a = parseFloat($('.price', row).val());
     console.log(a);
     var b = parseInt($('.quantity', row).val());
     console.log(b);
     var total = a * b;
     console.log(total);
     $('.total', row).value=total;
   }

   $('.price, .quantity').change(compute);

});
```

[image]

Comment: No, in the console you get `NaN` too. What tr is `$(this).closest('tr')` supposed to refer to?

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting total correctly use:

```
$('.total', row).val(total);
```

Comment: OP commented on a previous (deleted) answer that this still didn't work, but: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/VLRZmQ (yes it does).

Answer (score 0):

You don't get the value `NaN`, that's just the text that you put in the element from start. It never changes, because the code doesn't put any value in the element.

The jQuery object doesn't have a `value` property, use the `val` method:

```
$('.total', row).val(total);
```

Alternatively, the DOM element does have a `value` property, but then you have to get the element out from the jQuery object:

```
$('.total', row)[0].value = total;
```

Here is a working example using the `val` method:

```js
$(function(){
  
  function compute() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var a = parseFloat($('.price', row).val());
    console.log(a);
    var b = parseInt($('.quantity', row).val(), 10);
    console.log(b);
    var total = a * b;
    console.log(total);
    $('.total', row).val(total);
  }

  $('.price, .quantity').change(compute);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="price" value="10" />
            <input type="text" class="quantity" value="10,15" />
            <input type="text" class="total" value="NaN" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Notes:

- The function is not called when the page loads, so the total field will contain the text `NaN` until you edit some of the fields.
- The quantity field that has the value `"10,15"` is parsed using `parseInt`, so you will get the value `10` for quantity.

Comment: Thank you very much Guffa for your detailed answer, however, I still only get NaN as the value in the .total input field.

Comment: @Svedr: Then you have something in your code that makes it different from the example that I showed. I wrote the HTML code so that it would work with the code, but your code might be different. You can put a `console.log($('.total', row).length)` in the code to determine if you are able to reach the element at all. The length would be `1` if you found the element.

Comment: This is crazy, i've tried doing that and the result is 1 as you said. But i still get NaN in the total field :D Any ideas? It seems like the code works fine, but displaying it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @Svedr: Then log `$('.total', row)[0]` so that you see that you got the right element. Try doing something else to the element, like `$('.total', row).css('background', 'red')` to see if that works. As you have checked that you have a working value to put in the element, you basically close in from the other end to see what works and what doesn't to find out why you can't put that value in the element.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
 function compute()
 {
 var row=$(this).closest('tr');
 console.log(row);
 var a=parseFloat($('.price',row).val());
 var b=parseFloat($('.quantity',row).val());
 var c=a*b;
 console.log(c)
 $('.total',row).val(c.toFixed(2));
 }
 $('.quantity').change(compute);
});
```

```html
<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <td><input type="number" class="price" value=""/></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="quantity" value=""/></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="total" value=""/></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```